# How can I get terraform to use runcmd on Kali Linux?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to get terraform to execute the following script when the server is created. The python script below uses generic python3 libraries (requests, os, sys) for the most basic request of downloading a file from a website.

My userdata.yml:

```
#cloud-config
write_files:
  - path: /opt/tools/script.py
    encoding: b64
    content: ${script}
runcmd:
   - python3 /opt/tools/script.py
```

When I spawn an ubuntu server, this script works fine. The Python file is executed and I see the downloaded file when I log in.

I tried running this several times with a Kali Linux distro and it copies script.py into /opt/tools/ but it never executes it. Has anybody run into this before?

I've tried:

1. using python instead of python3
2. changing from the /opt/ folder
3. downloading a different file
4. doing something simple with the script like mkdir, touch

Thank you!

cloud-init.log - The put *** next to the 2 lines in the log that I see the script being referenced (checked via grep), but included a few lines before and after.

````
2019-09-30 16:21:28,632 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/instances/i-0b4f384079a131345/sem/config_write_files - wb: [644] 24 bytes                                                                                                                                                                                                    
2019-09-30 16:21:28,632 - helpers.py[DEBUG]: Running config-write-files using lock (<FileLock using file '/var/lib/cloud/instances/i-0b4f384079a131345/sem/config_write_files'>)                                                                                                                                                                 
***2019-09-30 16:21:28,800 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /opt/tools/script.py - wb: [644] 699 bytes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
***2019-09-30 16:21:28,854 - util.py[DEBUG]: Changing the ownership of /opt/tools/script.py to 0:0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
2019-09-30 16:21:28,854 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-network/config-write-files: SUCCESS: config-write-files ran successfully                                                                                                                                                                                                              
2019-09-30 16:21:28,854 - stages.py[DEBUG]: Running module growpart (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_growpart' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_growpart.py'>) with frequency always                                                                                                                                        
2019-09-30 16:21:28,854 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: init-network/config-growpart: running config-growpart with frequency always                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2019-09-30 16:21:28,854 - helpers.py[DEBUG]: Running config-growpart using lock (<cloudinit.helpers.DummyLock object at 0x7f89524961d0>)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
2019-09-30 16:21:28,854 - cc_growpart.py[DEBUG]: No 'growpart' entry in cfg.  Using default: {'mode': 'auto', 'devices': ['/'], 'ignore_growroot_disabled': False}                                                                                                                                                                               
2019-09-30 16:21:28,855 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['growpart', '--help'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
2019-09-30 16:21:28,859 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/691/mountinfo (quiet=False)                                                                                                                                               ```
````

Comment: Does Kali have `cloud-init` available? If not then I have no idea how you handle user data for it. Who publishes the base AMI for it?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - it looks like it's in the newest version of Kali. http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/cloud-init
It looks like the owner is actually Kali Linux (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=4c8c0cf0-881b-4cea-a067-abe6e0bb03ae) unless you're asking for something else.

Comment: Then the problem boils down to basically every other userdata issue: what does `/var/log/cloud-init.log` and `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` show?

Comment: updated OP with the cloud-init output that I saw. I can include more if needed. cloud-init-output.log just has the RSA key generation and networking information

Comment: @ydaetskcoR do you have any other suggestions for where I can look?